# How know if an attribute in Magento use options

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I want to know programmatically if a magento attribute use options or not to know if I must displayed this options.

For example a Text attribute don't use it and a Dropdown attributes have option. But how make programmatically this distinction ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);if($product->hasOptions){
        $optionsArr = $product->getOptions();
        foreach($optionsArr as  $optionKey => $optionVal)
        {

               $options=array();

                      foreach($optionVal->getValues() as $valuesKey => $valuesVal)
                        {

                            $options[]=array("key"=>$valuesVal->getId(), "val"=>$valuesVal->getTitle());


                        }
                   $custom_option["titles"][]=array("title"=>$optionVal->getTitle(),"title_id"=>$optionVal->getId(),"options"=>$options);     

                        //$optStr.= "</select>";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$attributeCode = 'code_here';
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode);
if ($attribute->getSourceModel()) {
    //it has options
} else {
    //it does not have options
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $attributeModel = Mage::getModel ( 'eav/entity_attribute' )->loadByCode ( 'catalog_product', 'attribute_code' );

                if ($attributeModel->getData ( 'frontend_input' ) == 'select') {
                    $attribute = Mage::getSingleton ( 'eav/config' )->getAttribute ( 'catalog_product', 'attribute_code' );
                    if ($attribute->usesSource ()) {
                        $options = $attribute->getSource ()->getAllOptions ( false );
                        $ifoptionfound = false;

                        if($options)
                            $ifoptionfound = true;

                    }

                }
```